# JavaScriptMVC installation

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, installation, javascriptmvc

I want to start my journey with JavaScriptMVC, but I really don't know how to install it properly. I mean I know, I may put it in public_html, but is it possible to place it in the system (like Rails for example?).

> Download the latest JavaScriptMVC.
> Unzip the folder on your file system
> or web server.  If you are using this
> on a webserver, unzip in a public
> folder where the server hosts static
> content.
>
> PRO TIP: Unzip these files as high in
> your apps folder structure as possible
> (i.e. don't put them under a
> javascriptmvc folder in your public
> directory).

These instructions are from a documentation. But it's ucnlear for me. Where should I unzip it? Should my apps be inside of JSMVC directory, or should they be independent? Especially these two lines are confusing:

> unzip in a public
> folder where the server hosts static
> content.
>
> don't put them under a
> javascriptmvc folder in your public
> directory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://forum.javascriptmvc.com/#Topic/32525000000577023

Here is an explanation.